# Java generics from Kotlin when verifying using Mockito?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, mockito

I'm using Kotlin 1.6.10, Mockito 4.0.0 and Java 8 and I have a Java interface defined like this:

```java
public interface MyInterface {
    <D, T extends MyObject<T, D>> T doThings(T myObject);
}
```

An implementation of this interface is used in a Kotlin application and we have a unit test in which we want to make sure that the `doThings` method is never called using Mockito. In Java I would just do like this:

```java
verify(myInterfaceInstance, never()).doThings(any());
```

But if I do this in Kotlin I get a compile-time error:

```kotlin
verify(myInterfaceInstance, never()).doThings(any())
```

> Not enough information to infer type variable D

I understand why this is the case, but I cannot get it to work. In this particular case I really don't care about the generic types, I just want to make sure the `doThings` is never called. I've tried a lot of different things, for example:

```kotlin
verify(myInterfaceInstance, never()).doThings<Any, MyObject<*, Any>>(any())
```

which fails with:

```
Type argument is not within its bounds.
Expected:
MyObject<MyObject<*, Any>!, TypeVariable(D)!>!
Found:
MyObject<*, Any!>!
```

and I've also tried:

```kotlin
verify(myInterfaceInstance, never()).doThings<Any, MyObject<*, *>>(any())
```

and several other permutations which all seem to fail with roughly the same error message.

So my question is, how can I do the equivalent of Java's `verify(myInterfaceInstance, never()).doThings(any());` in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles fine, but issues a couple of warnings, you could suppress them via respectful annotation:

```kotlin
@Suppress("TYPE_MISMATCH_WARNING", "UPPER_BOUND_VIOLATED_WARNING")
verify(myInterfaceInstance, never()).doThings<Any, MyObject<*, *>?>(any<MyObject<*, *>>())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Mockito answer, but would the Library Mockk help you? MockK is built specifically for Kotlin so it might have better supports for Generics handling.

The verification would look like:

```
verify(exactly = 0) { yourClass.doThings(any()) };
```

https://notwoods.github.io/mockk-guidebook/docs/mocking/verify/

https://mockk.io/#verification-atleast-atmost-or-exactly-times

Comment: Yeah it probably would, and thanks for the suggestion, but I would really like to understand how I can get it to work _without_ changing the library.

Comment: Of course, hope someone can help you

Comment: I just tried this, but I actually run into the same problem with MockK.